# How to accept Insecure Connection error in Firefox c#

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I wrote the below code but it doesn't work in Firefox 53.0, Selenium 3.3.1

```
  DesiredCapabilities opt= DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
  opt.SetCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
  opt.SetCapability("marionette", true);         
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```

Comment: Which language are you using? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am using c#. I get the +  $exception {"There is already an option for the marionette capability. Please use that instead.\r\nParameter name: capabilityName"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Java and the issue is with SSL Certificate, you need to add `ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS` as `true` to the DesiredCapabilities. The following code will solve your issue:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
driver.get("http://www.your_url.org/");
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @Tanya check out my updated Answer. Let me know if it helps you. Thanks

Comment: if you could give me the relevant code in C#, that would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle SSL error in Firefox browser is to accept untrusted certificate:

```
ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffProfile= prof.getProfile("myProfile");
ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
```

**For details on other browsers:**
http://www.guru99.com/ssl-certificate-error-handling-selenium.html#6